# Error adding GinIndex to model in Django with Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I am trying to add GinIndex to my model however, I am getting an error when migrating:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

This is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    guid_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1200)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(help_text="Tags", blank=True)
    likes= models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['title','content'],name='search_idx_post')
        ]
```

I was wondering what is causing this issue I cannot find how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want this index?  That is, what operations are you hoping to accelerate?

Comment: @jjanes I want to ad FTS to my project using Postgres

Comment: Then you need to build the index on the tsvector, not on the raw text field itself.  See somethig like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Answer (score 3):

Inside the migration file created by Django for adding the GinIndex, add the following:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import BtreeGinExtension
```

and then add this to the inside of the `operations` list, ie:

```
operations = [
    BtreeGinExtension()
    ...
]
```

Run this migration again and it should go through.